# Выборка из PostgreSQL по дате

Tags: java, postgresql, spring

Есть таблица зарегистрированных юзеров (id, name, create_date).

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", catalog = "test")
public class Users {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Integer id;
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
@CreatedDate
@Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnore
private ZonedDateTime createdDate;
}
```

Задача: вытянуть всех юзеров за год (от сегодня и до такого же дня в прошлом году) по дате регистрации и второй метод - всех юзеров за месяц (месяц передается как индекс)

```
 public List<Users> getAll() {
    List<Users> users = usersRepository.findAll();
    List<Integer> monthIndexList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Users user : users) {
        if (user.getCreatedDate().getMonthValue() == ZonedDateTime.now().getYear()) {
            monthIndexList.add(user);
        }
    }
    return users;
}
```

это тупо, но как временный вариант.

пробовал `List<Users> findAllByCreatedDateBetween(ZonedDateTime start, ZonedDateTime end);` - не работает, прилетает пустой массив.

```
public List<Users> getFindByLastYear() {
    return usersRepository.findAllByCreatedDateBetween(ZonedDateTime.now(), ZonedDateTime.now().minusMonths(12));;
}
```

Вопрос(ы):
1. Что не так с `findAllByCreatedDateBetween`? (читал [тут](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query-by-date)) должно работать.
2. Помочь составить *Spring* запрос, который сделает выборку за месяц по индексу месяца.

В `ZonedDateTime` есть метод `getMonthValue()`. Составленный *Spring*-запрос `findAllByCreatedDate_MonthValue(indexMonth)` - не работает.

Благодарю за любою помощь)

Comment: Что насчёт поддержки ZonedDateTime в JPA вообще? Даже в новой редакиции 2.2 ZonedDateTime не упоминается. Но заявлена поддержка (опять таки с версии 2.2) java.time.OffsetDateTime, который, судя по документации Java, как раз и предназначен для коммуниации с базами данных и для сетевых протоколов. И где Ваш findAllByCreatedDateBetween? Как именно не работает? Есть какое-то сообщение в консоле, логе? Может, прочитав его, сами быстрее догадаетесь в чём дело, чем любители стековерфлова угадают что не так?

Comment: с поддержкой ZonedDateTime норм, юзаем в проекте . На счет ошибок их нет http://take.ms/wXtYsX , наверное лучше бы были то было бы проще)))

Comment: Могу посоветовать включите трассировку SQL запросов